# Bootstrap multiple select click alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-select

I'm using bootstrap `multi-select`.I want to alert `gerekceli_indirimler` data when I select.But I can't alert.

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $(".gerekceli_indirimler").change(function(){
        alert($(this).find('checkbox').data('indirim'));
    });
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control gerekceli_indirimler" multiple="multiple" name="gerekceli_indirimler[]" data-plugin-multiselect id="gerekceli_indirimler[]">                                                
    <option data-indirim="10" value="1">İndirim1 (İndirim Oranı %10)</option>
    <option data-indirim="15" value="2">İndirim2 (İndirim Oranı %15)</option>
    <option data-indirim="20" value="3">İndirim3 (İndirim Oranı %20)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $(".gerekceli_indirimler").change(function(){
        alert($('.gerekceli_indirimler :selected').text());
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bv5kdf73/)